# Enumerated list, skipping the numbering of some items

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

Is it possible create an enumerated list with some of the items in the list not numbered? That is, is there an \item* command that will suppress the numbering of that particular item, and then continued the numbering with the next item (without skipping numbers)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can try `\item[]`.

Comment: Thank you! I discovered enumitem. It is working so far!